# Illustrator - Move a path vs. an anchor point with the anchor selection tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Sometimes when I click on an anchor point with the anchor selection tool, and then move my mouse, the entire shape will move. Other times, just the anchor will move.

How do you choose between moving the entire path or just the anchor point with the anchor selection tool?

Comment: Probably you miss the anchor point which is why the whole path is selected...

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are new to adobe illustrator.Same thing happened to me when I started using it.
When you click on selection tool (shorcut : V) then mouse pointer will change and shape will get changed accordingly.
When you click Direct selection tool(shortcut : A ) then clicking  on anchor point will move the complete image or shape.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use Direct Selection Tool to select anchor point and hold Option key to select entire path.